# Network profile activity is showing deleted comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, network-profile, deleted-comments

I stumbled upon [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196153/152859) question just now and of course went straight away to see [this user's activity across the network](https://stackexchange.com/users/1541171/meghraj-choudhary?tab=activity) where I noticed this:

> [image]

I scratched my head, reloaded three times, chanted the "Cache Buster" song but there were no such comments on Anna post:

> [image]

Which means... those two comments are now deleted and indeed, they do not show up in the [Meta account activity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/233186/meghraj-choudhary?tab=activity&sort=all) of that user.

I can only guess it's related to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196166/152859) that is still ongoing, causing weird behavior of the network account cache.

Comment: Still caching, server-side, I bet.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, but 17 hours??

Comment: How do you know when the comments were *deleted*? We only know when they were *posted*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters good point. Just a guess but still, deleted contents should override any cache.

Comment: I agree there is probably a problem here; just playing devils advocate. The comments are still there, nearly 20 minutes later. Perhaps the cache doesn't update until the user adds another post or comment somewhere.

Comment: OK, just did a quick test. I posted a comment and deleted it. It appeared in the network activity for one minute only and disappeared. So my best guess is the cache got broken at some point, and the dev who fixed it made some "hard refill" that is not dynamic i.e. just a mirror copy of the activity during the downtime. By the time of the refill, the comments were still there but as it's just static copy, it didn't get updated when the comments were deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in how the moderator ability "purge all comments" was being called - the network event aggregation service was unaware of these comment deletions.

A fix has been rolled out.

Comment: Nice, so it was happening for a long time?